# Parse a JSON object to get ResponseJSON from Jquery Ajax callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am hitting an API and would like to isolate the data contained in `responseJSON` returned from it. `console.log(mydata)` yields undefined, despite it clearly being there when I do `console.log(a)` (see screenshot).

My code:

```
function onComplete(a){ 
    console.log(a);
    return a['responseJSON']
}
function getData(whenDone){
     var data = $.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/');
         whenDone(data);

}
var mydata= getData(onComplete)
console.log(mydata);
```

[image]

Comment: `$.get()` is asynchronous: it returns a promise (jqXHR) object, not the data directly, so you'll need to restructure your code a bit to allow for the asynchronousnous.

Comment: @nnnnn somewhat new to this, can you explain how to get get the data from the promise object?

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate - the linked question covers this very comprehensively, but the short story is you can say `$.get(...).done(function(result) { /* use result here */ })`. The accepted answer on that question is very good, but very long, so you may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23819901/615754) gets you going faster.